# Intermittent "The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay" errors

Tags: c#, email, exception, smtp

I have a little C# email app that runs on a server. When launched it sends one email and then goes away. Most of the time it works fine, but every so often it will give the below error:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for joe123@msn.com
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at AppEmail.clsEmailMgr.SendEmail(MailMessage inMM, Int32 inTriesLimit, Int32 inSleepTime)
   at AppEmail.clsEmailMgr.MainProcess()
```

I have looked at some other postings on this type of error, but they tend to focus on the server setup - which I think is correct - or else this app would never work... and most of the time it does.

One other note: This app can get called multiple times fairly rapidly, so there can be situations in which different instances of itself are trying to send emails at almost the same time. Could a SPAM filter be blocking some of the email sending attempts? Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I would agree your problem is with the mail server - not your code.  Looks like an SMTP error.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs depending on the server setup... it does not prevent your code from working all the time... BUT it prohibits sending eMail with a sender/from with a domain not allowed and/or sending eMail to a domain not allowed... thus the mentioning of "relay" in the error...

Usually if you ask the server to send an eMail from a@b.com and the server is only setup for the domain c.com then this error comes up... otherwise it would be vulnerable to abuse by spammers (google for: spam open relay)... if your app needs to do such "relaying" for legit reasons then ask the mail server admin to configure the mail server that it allows relaying for the machine hosting your app...

Rapidly sending shouldn't be a problem except it could be perceived as an infected machine trying to send loads of spam... since you don't tell anything regarding the quantity per time unit this is pure speculation...

Comment: I think I have seen times when a particular email address will work, and then another times when it doesn't. Given that I am leaning more toward the SPAM possibility. I do not have a log for each email sent, so I don't know exactly how close together they are getting sent, but routinely emails are sent 1 second apart, and it is possible that an email or two is sent less than one second apart.

Comment: IF the same eMail adresses really work sometimes and sometimes not then there is aside from the SPAM protection still the possibility that you are dealing with an "Exchange cluster" with some inconsistency in its config... though I would lean towards SPAM protection too...

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar intermittent issue (unable to relay) with one of my application. I verified the SMTP host log and the error recorded there was 'Auth login' failure. Finally, we tried passing the SMTP credential username in UPN (universal Principal Name) format to the SMTP client.

Example: Use username@abc.com instead of domain/username

This will give consistent result.